# View logs from Azure Service Fabric in the OMS from another subscription

Tags: azure, logging, cloud, azure-service-fabric

I have an instance of the Service Fabric that resides in the German Cloud.  Since the OMS is not available in the German cloud, I need to use an OMS instance from West Europe. Because Of this, I cannot use the Service Fabric OMS connector solution.

Any information on how/what do I need to enable in order to connect these two services spread across subscriptions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this using [EventFlow](https://github.com/Azure/diagnostics-eventflow#oms-operations-management-suite).

It doesn't rely on an [Agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-diagnostic-collect-logs-without-an-agent) being present to upload to a Storage Account, but it accesses OMS directly.